# DynamoDB Query Input: How to retrieve all items where key value is not null

Tags: dynamodb-queries

I have the following schema:

```
resources:
 Resources:
   ChatDynamoDbTable:
     Type: "AWS::DynamoDB::Table"
     DeletionPolicy: Retain
     Properties:
       TableName: "chats-admin-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}"
       ProvisionedThroughput:
         ReadCapacityUnits: 1
         WriteCapacityUnits: 1
       AttributeDefinitions:
         - AttributeName: id
           AttributeType: S         
         - AttributeName: user_id
           AttributeType: S         
         - AttributeName: admin_type
           AttributeType: S         
       KeySchema:
         - AttributeName: id
           KeyType: HASH
       GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
       -
         IndexName: user_id-admin_type-index
         KeySchema:
           -
             AttributeName: user_id
             KeyType: HASH
           -
             AttributeName: admin_type
             KeyType: RANGE
         Projection:
           ProjectionType: ALL
         ProvisionedThroughput:
           ReadCapacityUnits: 1
           WriteCapacityUnits: 1
```

I need to fetch all items where the `admin_type` matches the key I supply.

I tried the following and it failed because I've not specified the value for `user_id`:

> "error_message":"ValidationException: Query condition missed key
> schema element: user_id

```
input := &dynamodb.QueryInput{
        TableName:              aws.String(table),
        IndexName:              aws.String("user_id-admin_type-index"),
        KeyConditionExpression: aws.String("#admin_type = :admin_type"),
        ExpressionAttributeNames: map[string]*string{
            "#admin_type": aws.String("admin_type"),
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
            ":admin_type": {
                S: aws.String(a.AdminType),
            },
        },
    }
```

How can I modify the above to fetch all items where `admin_type` matches my key? (basically all items matching `admin_type` without worrying about the value of `user_id`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DynamoDB API offers two basic means of fetching data; `query` and `scan`.

The `query` operation requires you to specify the primary key.  When you have a composite primary key (partition key + sort key), you can:

- Specify only the partition key (you'll get back everything in the partition)
- Specify both the partition key and sort key (you'll get back a single item)

There is no option with the `query` operation to specify only the sort key.

To fetch items by sort key *only*, you'll need to use the `scan` operation.  Alternatively, you could create a secondary index with a primary key set to your sort key (in your case, the `admin_type`).  This would allow you to fetch items by `admin_type`, regardless of the `user_id`.

Comment: Many thanks, I created an additional GSI to solve the issue.